# Make undefined variable an error in php

Tags: php

I have the following code snippet:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
print $bla;
print 7;
?>
```

which prints out a warning that `bla` is undefined, but continues afterwards. I want php to throw an error and stop code execution when an undefined variable is encountered. How to do that?

The above is just an example. I want to handle EACH undefined variable within a multi thousand block clode piece.

Comment: You might want to use a linter to detect these possible errors in advance. For example, you could use [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) with this plugin: https://github.com/sirbrillig/phpcs-variable-analysis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write your own error handler. And make it halt execution when you encounter this type of notice. Take a look at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

A small and simple example:

```
function new_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    switch ($errno) {
      case E_NOTICE:
        if (strstr($errstr, 'Undefined variable')) {
          die('Undefined variable found');
        }
      break;
    }
}

set_error_handler('new_error_handler');

echo $foo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement an error handler with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and put a `die` inside.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!isset($bla)){
   throw new Exception('bla variable is not defined');
}
```

Comment: sorry i didnt read this "The above is just an example. I want to handle EACH undefined variable..." :)