# Why is is_null throwing an exception on an unset variable

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, php-7

Deep inside a Laravel terminal command I have the following code:

```php
<?php
/* ... */

class TrackShipment extends Command
{

   /* ... */

    public function handle()
    {
      /* ... */
         if (is_null($eventHook) || $eventHook->uri != $statusHook->uri) {
          /* ... */
         }
     }
}
```

when this part of the code executes the process dies with the following exception

```
ErrorException  : Undefined variable: eventHook
```

Which is surprising because I've used similar code in all sorts of places and PHP will return true when is_null is called on an unset variable though it will complain about it on stderr with a notice.

I assume Laravel is adjusting the PHP settings from within it's code to make is_null throw an exception instead of print a notice to stderr. What is this setting? How would I replicate the excepiton in vanilla php7.2?

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537562/make-undefined-variable-an-error-in-php/16537600 is still valid or if it's outdated.

Comment: `NULL` and not defined variables are different, for me it's normal you have this kind of error. You have to add a `isset($eventHook) and ...` in your conditions. The exception is normal. I guess it depends on your `error_reporting` level

Comment: try to use `empty()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel is most likely using the set_error_handler to set a custom error handler function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

where you can define a custom way to manager errors.

Here is where: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a05b9dcb3b1e8069b59a9af90d0b157c30382131/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L43

Sorry about the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function `is_null` trigger notice if a variable is not defined. The Laravel convert that notice to an exception.

There are two function You can use to check undefined variable that will not trigger notice.

1. `isset` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
2. `empty` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

The first will return false for null, so You have to negate it.